# How do you get past the owls?

Tags: year-walk

In *Year Walk*, the ghost leads you to a locked door with two owls. It seems like the next step, but how do you progress?

Comment: I posted the answer below, but I insist that you explore just a bit more before reading it. Have fun :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owls must be tapped in a specific pattern that is given by the hanging wooden doll found in the outhouse. You activate the wooden doll by spinning her head continuously to the doll's right (you swipe to the left). You have to swipe quickly to get the head to spin without resetting. The doll will then play a song and point with the left, right, or both arms to the owl carvings at her side. Repeat that pattern with the live owls found in the tree.